# Lista de valores em uma session usando NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou usando os módulos **express-session** e **express** e estou precisando criar uma lista de valores em um item de uma session para que em determinado momento vá adicionando valores nela. 
Ex:

req.session.categoria = "Incluir chave e valor nesta propriedade"

Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando o seguinte código abaixo:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var session = require('express-session');
var express = require('express');

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

app.use(session({
secret: 's3ssIon',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

req.session.formula = [];

req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1

req.session.formula.push(req.session.views);

res.end(req.session.views + ' views')

});

app.get('/resultado', function (req, res) {

req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1

req.session.formula.push(req.session.views);

res.end(req.session.views + ' views')

});

app.get('/fim', function (req, res) {

req.session.destroy();

res.end('Session encerrada')
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Connected");
});
```

Configurei a Session, criei 3 rotas (raiz, resultado e fim), utilizei o [] para criar o array e o método push para incluir os valores.